# Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

Trying to add an object into an array within the state of this component, unable to concat the new object to array without a 'property undefined' error.

I have been able to get this to work with a 'shallow' state with an array but would like to have , would prefer to have it work with separate array inside.

The state

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        this.state = {
          show: false,
          id: null,
          name: 'New Task',
          timerOn: false,
          seconds: 0,
          minutes:0,
          hours:0,
          complete: {
            todayId: null,
            list: []
          }
        }
      }
```

Method for updating state, making a copy of the 'controls' (minutes, seconds, start etc) resetting the state back to it's initial values taking a copy of the state and applying it to the array:

```
    completeTaskHandler = () => {
      if (this.state.seconds === 0 && this.state.minutes === 0 && this.state.hours === 0) {
        alert('Please Provide a name');
      }
      else {
        const end = new Date();
        let finishedTask = new Object ({
          start: this.state.id,
          end: end,
          name: this.state.name,
          seconds: this.state.seconds,
          minutes: this.state.minutes,
          hours: this.state.hours,});

        this.setState((prevState,props) => {
          return {
            start: null,
            show: false,
            id: null,
            name: 'task',
            timerOn: false,
            seconds: 0,
            minutes:0,
            hours:0,
            complete: prevState.complete.list.concat(finishedTask)
          }
        });
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give more clarity to help , Please?

Comment: Try to log 'prevState.complete.list' and see if it's the object you expect it to be (an array)

Comment: Since list is an array. Change to complete: [...prevState.complete.list, finishedTask]

Answer (score 1):

You are doing concat on an array. Since list is an array.

Use previous state to push new value to an array. Check below solution for better understanding

```
  this.setState((prevState,props) => {
      return {
        start: null,
        show: false,
        id: null,
        name: 'task',
        timerOn: false,
        seconds: 0,
        minutes:0,
        hours:0,
        complete: [...prevState.complete.list, finishedTask]
      }
    });
```